# How to merge two tables with computation MS Access?

Tags: c#, ms-access

I have 2 tables, almost the same attributes. Let's say in table1 i have these attributes.

```
Item        Quantity        Unit Net Price        Total Net Price
asd            2                 22                    44
```

And, in table2 :

```
Item        Quantity        Unit Gross Price
asd            1                 20
```

You can see the difference of each table.

`Unit Net Price` = `Unit Gross Price` * `1.10`

`Total Net Price` = `Unit Net Price` * `Quantity`

I need to insert table2 to table1 and at the same time `Unit Net Price` and 
`Total Net Price` will be computed. I can't make the correct query statement for this. So far i'm working with this statement.

```
"INSERT INTO [table1] ([Item], [Quantity], [Unit Net Price], [Total Net Price]) SELECT * FROM [table2] WHERE [Unit Net Price] = [Unit Gross Price] * 1.10 AND [Total Net Price] = [Quantity] * [Total Net Price]"
```

I'm using `OleDBCommand` for this query. Anyone can give me the correct query statement or appropriate solution for this?

Comment: look up this method which is part of the `DataTable` Object `MergeAll` there are plenty examples on how to easily do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a SQL solution use this.
The calculations go into the SELECT clause, not the WHERE clause.

Also note that you can't use a field you just calculated ([Unit Net Price]) to calculate another field ([Total Net Price]), all calculations must be based on fields from table2.

```
INSERT INTO [table1] ([Item], [Quantity], [Unit Net Price], [Total Net Price])
SELECT 
    [Item], 
    [Quantity],
    [Unit Gross Price] * 1.10 AS [Unit Net Price],
    [Quantity] * [Unit Gross Price] * 1.10 AS [Total Net Price]
FROM [table2]
```

Comment: thank you sir! This works fine. I'm having a little trouble with updating the table object. Values were save in the database but, the datagrid is not updating. I'll try to troubleshoot this, thanks again.